# Rails 3: Redirect loop caused by appended `/` to URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger, redirect-loop

**Background Info**

setup: Rails 3 + Apache2 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.7

I deployed a Rails 3 app to a sub URI on my domain (which is also a Rails 3 app). I'm using Phusion Passenger 3.0.7 to deploy my Rails apps.

**The Problem**

When navigating to http://mydomain.com/suburi/ I get a `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` message. Notice the appended `/`. However, when navigating to http://mydomain.com/suburi/home, or http://mydomain.com/suburi everything works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my Apache configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  CheckSpelling on

  PassengerFriendlyErrorPages Off

  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /www/mydomain/public

  <Directory /www/mydomain/public>
      RackEnv production
      Options FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
  </Directory>

  RackBaseURI /suburi
  <Directory /www/mydomain/public/suburi>
      RackEnv production
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
      Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do   

    # snipped code that wouldn't affect anything...

    root :to => "home#index"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit ended up being the `mod_speling` Apache module I had enabled via `CheckSpelling on`. After disabling the module, I had no further problems.